# DateTime parsing in c#:getting a 'System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime' error

Tags: c#, parsing

I have a dataset in a .csv file in a local folder, below is a sample row of the data, it has 13 attributes to each item.

I am parsing this data in C#, my code has been working for 2 years and I cannot remember

The code reading the .csv file is, this section is parsing the data into compiledList.

```
static string loadFile(string fileLocation)
    {
        string text = "";

        try
        {
            text = File.ReadAllText(fileLocation);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error has occured...");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        return text;
    }
    static ConcurrentBag<Item> interpretFile(string text, ConcurrentBag<Item> compiledList)
    {
        String[] substrings = text.Split('\n');
        int settlementPeriod = -1;   int totalSP = -1;

        foreach (string line in substrings)
        {
            String[] items = line.Split(',');
            if (items[0] == "HDR")
            {
                settlementPeriod = int.Parse(items[3]);
                if (settlementPeriod > 48)
                    settlementPeriod -= 48;
                if (settlementPeriod < 0)
                    settlementPeriod += 48;

                totalSP = getTotalSettlementPeriod(DateTime.ParseExact(items[2], "yyyyMMdd", null), settlementPeriod);
            }
            if (items[0] == "BOALF")
            {
                //Item Bid = new Item(items);
                Item Bid = new Item
                {
                    recordType = items[0],
                    unitID = items[1],
                    acceptID = float.Parse(items[2]),
                    acceptTime = DateTime.ParseExact(items[3], "yyyyMMddHHmmss", null),
                    deemedFlag = ToBoolean(items[4]),
                    soFlag = ToBoolean(items[5]),
                    storFlag = ToBoolean(items[6]),
                    fromTime = DateTime.ParseExact(items[7], "yyyyMMddHHmmss", null),
                    fromLevel = float.Parse(items[8]),
                    toTime = DateTime.ParseExact(items[9], "yyyyMMddHHmmss", null),
                    toLevel = float.Parse(items[10]),
                    settlementPeriod = settlementPeriod,
                    totalSP = totalSP
                };
                compiledList.Add(Bid);
```

Sample item from the .csv is:

[image]

When I open the data set in Notebad below is what i see:

[image]

Note that `items[0]` is the first colum from the about sample data set.  there the data which I am now having issues with is column 4 which is '2.02E+13' shown above.

What that actually is '20191211202600'  which is the 'yyyymmddhhmmss' in number format.  I do not know what has changed such that the below is giving me an error.

```
acceptTime = DateTime.ParseExact(items[3], "yyyyMMddHHmmss", null)
```

`

The error that I am getting is:

> System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.'

I would appreciate your assistance and let me know if further clarification is required.

Thanks

Comment: What is the actual value of `items[3]` PRIOR to `acceptTime` attempting to ParseExact?  Use a breakpoint right before.  I suspect that you're not seeing the full string of numbers in `items[3]` and instead pulling the exponent notation.  Ashkan's answer below also seems to suggest this - but you validating this case would provide an exact answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the problem is with your C# code, the columns which contain date format `yyyymmddhhmmss` should be of type string, where they are now treated as a number. This problem arises from the program you are saving the CSV file (for example excel or google spreadsheets) you need to change the column data type to string (as it is now automatically detected as a number).

Comment: The data set is coming from a WebAPI and my initial code is just downloading the .csv files and saving them

On the code could I parse the new format into datetime, and how would i do this?

Comment: @MohammadHussain can you confirm this by manually downloading csv file and opening it via notepad (not excel)?

Comment: I have provited a screenshot of the data when opened in a Notepad, to me it still looks like a string and not a number, then why would this issue arise all of a sudden?

Comment: ok, as you see, they are correct in the csv files (when opened as text) however if after download you are opening them with excel (and maybe edit save) causes the problem. and also make sure that the class you are mapping the csv files to, has string data type for those columns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204085/discussion-between-mohammad-hussain-and-ashkan-mobayen-khiabani).

Answer (score 0):

The following works in .NET fiddle (https://dotnetfiddle.net/), can you verify the string that is being used in the call to `DateTime.ParseExact`? Perhaps the string is not equal to what you would expect at runtime.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("20191211202600", "yyyyMMddHHmmss", null));
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
12/11/2019 8:26:00 PM
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for you response.  I agree with what you have said.  I think the data provider has now changed the format of the cell into number and it longer is a string.  How would I overcome this? to pass into my function and convert into date time to get the desire out put per what you have shown above.